# Search file in directory using complex pattern

Tags: c#, search, file, design-patterns

I am looking for a C# library for getting files or directory from a directory using a complex pattern like the one used in Ant:

- `dir1/dir2/**/SVN/*` --> Matches all files in SVN directories that are located anywhere in the directory tree under dir1/dir2
- `**/test/**` --> Matches all files that have a test  element in their path, including test as a filename.
- ...

Do I need to code it myself? extract what I want from NAnt? Or this library exists and my google skill sucks.

`Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)` doesn't handle directory pattern and [NDepend.Helpers.FileDirectoryPath](http://www.codeplex.com/FileDirectoryPath) neither (it's a great library for path manipulation by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding it yourself wouldnt be that hard.

Just use a correctly formulated regular expression with System.IO methods to build the full path

Comment: This answer accepted is what the! Ok check this **/some(dir)/a*.txt" you need to replace "(" with "\\(" and "." with "\\." before to get regular expression. This is your "wouldnt be that hard" code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.java

Answer (score -1):

Are you comfortable with defining "*" as "anything but slash" and "**" as "anything at all"?  If so, the regex conversion seems straightforward.

```
*   -> [^\/]*
**  -> .*
```

Then it's a matter of recursively enumerating all files, and checking if their paths match the regex.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why you voted this down?  Help me learn!

Comment: It is a start but you need to escape regex characters as some characters are allowed for path like "\\" or "(" or even "."; But even with that it will have lots of flaws for example: "./somefolder/**/somefile.txt" => First dot means current folder second one is part of filename; So you need to expand first dot with current dir before checking the match,,,,